# How to reduce size of error.log in Nginx?

Tags: nginx

I have no idea how to fix this...

```
2019/01/14 05:15:02 [alert] 27307#27307: *9 write() to "/var/log/nginx/access.log" failed (28: No space left on device) while logging request, client: 108.162.226.175, server: titomi.cf, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock", host: "titomi.cf"

2019/01/14 05:15:22 [error] 27307#27307: *11 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory in /var/www/test/lib/common.lib.php on line 1443" while reading response header from upstream, client: 162.158.118.78, server: test.titomi.cf, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "test.titomi.cf"
```

I think this is access.log error size
How can I reduce the size of access.log?

Comment: When I look at disk amount, /dev/vda1       41233708 41117960         0 100% /

Comment: /dev/vda1       41233708 41117960         0 100% /

Comment: I dunno how to remove this dump files

Answer (score 1):

You probably need log rotation to rotate the logs.

sudo vim /etc/logrotate.d/nginx

```
    /var/log/nginx/*.log {
            daily
            missingok
            rotate 14
            compress
            notifempty
            create 0640 www-data adm
 }
```

Daily: Rotate the logs daily basis
missingok: Do not give output if log is missing
Rotate 14: Will keep the last 14 logs
Compress: Will the compress the old copies of the log files.

You can run the logrotate

logrotate /var/log/nginx/